# Unable to Create a Directory within a System Rescue .iso

Tags: linux, permissions, iso-image

I am currently trying to create a directory within a mounted System Rescue `.iso`. The below list of commands is what I have done in an attempt to gain the ability to create a directory. The goal is to add the recovery files inside a file in the newly created directory so that I can boot *and* restore from the same disc.

```
[root@vm2 Utilities]# mount -o loop,rw /current/iso/macriumREG41.iso /mnt/temp/
[root@vm2 Utilities]# cd /mnt/temp/
[root@vm2 temp]# mkdir V4.1
mkdir: cannot create directory V4.1': Read-only file system
[root@vm2 temp]# mount -o remount,rw /mnt/temp/
[root@vm2 temp]# mkdir V4.1
mkdir: cannot create directory V4.1': Input/output error
[root@vm2 temp]# ls -l /current/iso/macriumREG41.iso
-rwxr--r--. 1 root nfsnobody 277413888 Dec  7 22:17   /current/iso/macriumREG41.iso
[root@vm2 temp]# chmod 777 !$
chmod 777 /current/iso/macriumREG41.iso
[root@vm2 temp]# mkdir V4.1
mkdir: cannot create directory `V4.1': Input/output error
```

Additional information:

```
[root@vm2 temp]# file /current/iso/macriumREG41.iso
/current/iso/macriumREG41.iso: ISO 9660 CD-ROM filesystem data 'RESCUE ' (bootable)
```

Any suggestions as to how I should proceed?

Comment: /current/iso/macriumREG41.iso: ISO 9660 CD-ROM filesystem data 'RESCUE                         ' (bootable)

Comment: Check the syslog or dmesg after the mount & remount & IO errors, might have some more useful messages. And if you're using a USB, you might be able to write to another partition.

Answer (score 0):

`macriumREG41.iso` contains ISO 9660 CD-ROM filesystem. This type of filesystem is created once and never modified. To modify it, you rather create it anew as a whole with a tool like `genisoimage` (`mkisofs`).

What you were trying to do was like creating a directory on a CD-ROM. In case of a physical CD-ROM this is physically impossible in the first place, but it's also impossible because of limitations of ISO 9660 filesystem. In case of a mounted image (your case) only the latter cause applies but it's still enough to make it impossible.

You need to create another `.iso` file based on the directories, files and boot data from the original image and your additional directories and files. Remember you want to keep it bootable. I have no experience with this, I cannot guide you in detail. Study `man 1 genisoimage`. I also found [this old answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/46647/693277) that recommends [ISO Master](http://littlesvr.ca/isomaster/); I think the software is available as `isomaster` package in Ubuntu, Debian etc.